# django how to use template tags

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-errors

So I want to use this getattribute function (found on this link) https://snipt.net/Fotinakis/django-template-tag-for-dynamic-attribute-lookups/

in my django templates. I created a templatetags folder in my app folder where my models.py is. I also created and saved an empty **inint**.py file in the templatetags folder. I then created a file called getattribute.py in the template tags folder and copy-pasted the snippet found in the link above into the getattribute.py file and saved the file.

This is what my template looks like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.first_name }} {{form.last_name }} <br>
            {{ form.username }} {{ form.password }} <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
        </form>

{% load getattribute %}

{% for field, error in form.errors.items %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
        {% with field_obj=form|getattribute:field %}
            {{ field_obj.label }}{{ error | striptags }}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

This is how my models.py looks.

```
class Users(models.Model):
    alpha_field = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$', message='Name can only contain letters')
    user_id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    username = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='first Name', validators=[alpha_field])
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[alpha_field])
    password = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
```

My forms.py is this.

```
class UsersForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        widgets = {'password':forms.PasswordInput()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super( UsersForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[ 'username' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Username"
        self.fields[ 'first_name' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="First Name"  
        self.fields[ 'last_name' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Last Name"
        self.fields[ 'password' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Password"
        self.fields['first_name'].label='first Name'
```

and this is my views.py

```
def home_page(request):
    form = UsersForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UsersForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    c.update({'form':form})
    return render_to_response('home_page.html', c)
```

Now, when I run the server, the form is displayed with no errors. However, if I purposely not fill out the first name section and hit submit, it says "This field is required."
I want it to say the verbose name and the snippet is supposed to make it say the verbose name if, in my template, I use {{ field_obj.label }}, right? But it is not display the verbose name for some reason. I'm guessing it is because I'm not using the templatetags properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, it may help to have a clean method:

```
def clean(self):
    first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')

    if password is None:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This is a custom error message.')

    return self.cleaned_data
```

Then, in your template, you can have code like:

```
    {{ form.first_name }}
    {% if form.first_name.errors %}
        &nbsp;{{form.first_name.errors.as_text}}
    {% endif %}
```

Otherwise, django's default form validation will treat all your inputs as required, and provide that generic message.

Another option, from the docs, is to define error messages at the form field level: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/

```
name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Please enter your name'})
```

This will add the custom error message based on the error type, so in your case, you could use something like:

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='first Name', validators=[alpha_field], error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a first name'})
```

Comment: Hm, interesting. Okay thanks. What does the line 'self.cleaned_data.get('first_name') and then the line return self.cleaned_data do anyways?

Comment: In your view when you call form.is_valid(), it looks at data in your request.POST and binds it to your form. Reading through the docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/
The form.is_valid()

Comment: In your view when you call form.is_valid(), it looks at data in your request.POST and binds it to your form. Reading through the docs at: 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

The form.is_valid() method basically does form validation (if you have any validators on your form fields), and self.cleaned_data is basically your validated fields. 

As for why we return self.cleaned_data - I've been using django 1.5,  which for some reason required that form.clean() return a dictionary of cleaned items. The development version seems to have removed that requirement.